# Strange behavior of the array_slice function

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have a code that executes some action on a part of the array in a loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i<=sizeof($posts); $i+=21){
    $postsToCheck = array_slice($posts, $i, $i+20);
    //var_dump($postsToCheck);
    doSomething($postsToCheck);
}
```

But it doesn't work the way it should. Each part of the array should contain 20 records, but this is only the case in the first iteration. The second one has 41 records and the third one has 62.

How to divide this array into 20 records in each iteration?

Comment: well yeah, why are you trying to slice an array inside a loop?

Comment: The 3rd argument is the length of the slice, not where it stops.  You are incrementing `$i` in your loop, so the length will increase too.

Comment: `$i+=21` in the second loop array_slice($posts, 21, 41)

Comment: @treyBake I use an external API that has limits in the size of the sent data. So I want to divide the array into smaller ones and pass this data to the function that sends data to API in several requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be replaced with [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/array_chunk):

```
foreach (array_chunk($posts, 20) as $postsToCheck) {
     doSomething($postsToCheck);
}
```

And correct `for` loop is:

```
for($i = 0; $i<=sizeof($posts); $i+=20){
    // third argument of `array_slice` is "size of slice", it is 20
    $postsToCheck = array_slice($posts, $i, 20); 
    doSomething($postsToCheck);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct behaviour for array_slice within a loop like that.

You can use something like this:

```
    foreach (array_chunk($posts, 20) as $chunkedPosts) {
        doSomething($chunkedPosts);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_chunk,

```
 $lenght = 20;

 array_chunk($posts, 20) => /* after then go loop */
```

if you want to array_slice

```
for($i = 0; $i<=sizeof($posts); $i+=($lenght)){
    $postsToCheck = array_slice($posts, $i, $lenght); 
    doSomething($postsToCheck);
}
```